# Emacs outline view possible in CC mode?

Tags: emacs

I'm an Eclipse addict trying to get more comfortable with Emacs for C code. Is there a way to get an outline view of a C file, similar to the view on the right of the image below, in Emacs in CC mode?

[image: Eclipse Outline View]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/images/outlineView.png))</sub>

Answer (score 9):

Check out [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/), the Emacs Code Browser.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely check out [Speedbar](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeedBar).  That will make a new Emacs frame that can be used as an outline.  If you want something in the same frame, check out [Sr Speedbar](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SrSpeedbar).

Answer (score 1):

ECB is an integration tool that uses Speedbar anyways. It offers a lot more functionality though - the file browser with VC integration is particularly nice IMO. All in all I think that if one needs to make Emacs look more like Eclipse he needs ECB.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Speedbar](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeedBar), which will provide this kind of functionality in any mode that has imenu support (including C).